# How to handle error log in framework

Tags: php, frameworks

This is sample code to catch error in PHP.

```
<?php
// Error handler function.
function customError($errno, $errstr)
{
    echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr";
}

// Set error handler.
set_error_handler('customError');

// Trigger error.
echo($test);
?>
```

I am using frameworks. i dont know how to log errors. I tried by giving `function customError($errno, $errstr)` in modal and I called from controller it doesn't work for me. How to handle error in frameworks?

Comment: You should probably tell us what framework you are using.

Comment: you've got to at least say which framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to throw exception. Inside your main execution loop catch exceptions and output them into log file.